# Right Click Popup Menu Slow

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom, jquery-selectors, dom-traversal

I have implemented a right click popup menu on my KendoUI Grid.

The problem is, is that it is slow.

When you right click the script needs to get the id of the row which was clicked. I am doing this with:

```
salesGrid.on('mouseup', '[role="row"]', function(e){
  button = e.which ;
  if(button == 3)
  {
    $(this).bind("contextmenu",function(e){
      return false
    });

    var id = null ;
    id = $('td', this).find('.id-span').data('id') // ~500ms
```

I have also tried:

```
id = $(this).children('td').children('.id-span').data('id') ;
```

And:

```
id = $('td:first span', this).data('id') ;
```

All of which take about 500ms to execute, which is too long in terms of user experience.

Here is the table it is traversing:

```
<tr data-uid="16e14dc2-a2fa-4979-a1ff-cd5113223aa6" role="row">
    <td role="gridcell"><span class="id-span" data-id="1">A</span></td>
    <td role="gridcell">3</td>
    <td role="gridcell">Lenze</td>
    <td role="gridcell"><span class="popoverintel" data-trigger="hover" data-placement="bottom" data-part-id="1">33.8202-E</span></td>
    <td role="gridcell">Supply</td>
    <td role="gridcell">New</td>
    <td role="gridcell">3</td>
    <td role="gridcell">€</td>
    <td role="gridcell">575.00</td>
    <td role="gridcell">1725.00</td>
</tr>
```

Is there a way to make this faster?

Comment: what is `this` in this context, is it the table, row, cell, or a content within the cell

Comment: Try something like `$('.id-span', $(this).closest('tr')).data('id')`

Comment: @Arun P Johny I have added the context.

Comment: How about `$(this).children().first().children().first().data("id")`?

Comment: $('.id-span', $(this).closest('tr')).data('id') is the same speed :(

Comment: Or `this.firstChild.firstChild.getAttribute("data-id");`

Comment: $(this).children().first().children().first().data("id") Also the same, it is definitley this line because if I make id = 1; it is rapid.

Comment: @Ian Still the same kind of speed.

Comment: Does it change anything if you do `.attr("data-id")` instead of `.data("id")`?

Comment: you can also improve the selector `'[role="row"]'` by `'tr[role="row"]'`

Comment: @Arun P Johny Thanks that seems to have fixed it, possibly it was due to the fact I have another table that had similar attributes so it must have been scanning through them all.

Comment: how much time it is taking now

Comment: @Arun P Johny About 10ms instead of ~400ms :)

Comment: @Arun P Johny Can you put what you said as answer and I'll accept.

Comment: @imperium2335 sure, anyway the result is superb, shows just how important is to use the right selector

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try changing the selector `'[role="row"]'` by `'tr[role="row"]'`